# Python use slipt function cant slipt that input function string add to dict

Tags: python

Homework I need to complete

Goal: Create a program to sort student names and student ID（number）, create a dict and print it out

I created an empty dict, used the input function, and then used the slipt function to split, the splitting symbol is @, and then imported into the empty dict

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'，the told me that is cant hash

i want to fix it，thanks

```
stList = {}
userInput = str(input('input studens name:'))
numInput = str(input('input studens ID:'))
userInput = userInput.split('@')
numInput = numInput.split('@')
print(stList)
```

[pycharm screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKPap.png)

Comment: You don't give us all your code and especially the problematic line :  `stList[userInput] = numInput`

Answer (score 0):

when you write the line `userInput = userInput.split('@')` it returns a list of size 2 , lists can't act as keys to a dictionary (they are not hash-able) , if you care to explain what exactly you want to achieve then I can help you

Comment: I need to input string, use @ to separate, then add to dict, sort students ID (value) and print

Answer (score 0):

Python definition of Hashable is:

An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a `hash()` method).

So as a list is obviously a mutable object, it can't be hashed.

Internally, hash() method calls `__hash__()` method of an object which are set by default for any object.

Your problem:

1. First thing is that input() function already takes `input()` as a string, so you don't need to explicitly put `str(input())`
2. When you say `stList[userInput] = numInput`, you are trying to hash the key of the dictionary that is userInput, which is btw a list (because `split()` function returns a list of strings)

   As lists are mutable and unhashable, it throws error, there is popular way of handling it by using tuples. You can easily convert the list to tuple and then hash it as it's an immutable object in Python.

Full clean code:

```
stList = {}
userInput = input('input studens name: ')
numInput = input('input studens ID: ')
userInput = userInput.split('@')
numInput = numInput.split('@')
assert len(userInput) == len(numInput) # To check that the number of students and the number of id numbers match
for i in range(len(userInput)):
    stList[userInput[i]] = numInput[i]
```

Result after running the above code:

```
>>> stList = {}
>>> userInput = input('input studens name: ')
input studens name: BRAD@LEO@KILLUA@MUFFY
>>> numInput = input('input studens ID: ')
input studens ID: 1@2@3@4
>>> userInput = userInput.split('@')
>>> numInput = numInput.split('@')
>>> assert len(userInput) == len(numInput)
>>> userInput
['BRAD', 'LEO', 'KILLUA', 'MUFFY']
>>> numInput
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> for i in range(len(userInput)):
...     stList[userInput[i]] = numInput[i]
...
>>> stList
{'BRAD': '1', 'LEO': '2', 'KILLUA': '3', 'MUFFY': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this:

```py
stList = {}
userInput = str(input('input studens name:'))
numInput = str(input('input studens ID:'))
userInput = userInput.split('@') # A list with student names
numInput = numInput.split('@') # A list with id numbers

assert len(userInput) == len(numInput) # To make sure the number of students and their id numbers match
stList = {userInput[i]: numInput[i] for i in range(len(userInput))}
```

Comment: Hello, I don't quite understand why this sentence is written like this.     stList：dict = {key：value}

Comment: Read about python's [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

Error comes from the problematic line you didn't give but that is present in your screenshot
`stList[userInput] = numInput`

userInput is a list as it is the result of split function.

You can't use a list as a key of dictionary.

However, you can add each value of the list ad key of the dictionary.

```py
for username in userInput:
   stList[username] = numInput
```